# split format string of (format t ...)

Tags: common-lisp

Sometimes I like to output some text with `(format t ..)`.
To prevent long unreadable format-strings in source code, and get the output easily aligned, I use `(format t (concatenate 'string ....)`.

Example:

```
(format t (concatenate 'string 
                       "some output~%"
                       "  error-msg: ~a~%"
                       "  uiop-cwd: ~a~%"
                       "  uiop-file-exists: ~a~%")
        "error foo"
        (uiop:getcwd)
        (uiop:file-exists-p "hello_world.bmp"))
```

Is there a more idiomatic and at-compile-time way to do the same in Common Lisp?

Comment: You could use `#.(concatenate ...)` to make it do the concatenation at read-time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is an equivalent format string that makes use of the [Tilde newline](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/22_cic.htm) format directive, which ignores the following newline and spaces (until the next visible character). In order to indent with spaces as you did, I wrote the forced newline `~%` before the spaces:

```
(format t 
        "some output~
       ~%   error-msg: ~a~
       ~%   uiop-cwd: ~a~
       ~%   uiop-file-exists: ~a~%"
        "error foo"
        (uiop:getcwd)
        (uiop:file-exists-p "hello_world.bmp"))
```

(NB. This is a single string so there is no concatenation to be done at compile-time.)

Answer (score 3):

You can do quite well with something like:

```
(defun fmt (to control/s &rest args-to-format)
  (declare (dynamic-extent args-to-format)) ;?OK
  (apply #'format to (if (listp control/s)
                         (apply #'concatenate 'string control/s)
                       control/s)
         args-to-format))

(define-compiler-macro fmt (&whole form to control/s &rest args-to-format)
  (cond
   ((stringp control/s)
    `(format ,to ,control/s ,@args-to-format))
   ((and (listp control/s)
         (eql (first control/s) 'quote))
    ;; literal
    (destructuring-bind (_ thing) control/s
      (declare (ignore _))
      (print "here")
      (if (and (listp thing) (every #'stringp thing))
          `(format ,to ,(apply #'concatenate 'string thing) ,@args-to-format)
        form)))
   (t
    form)))
```

The compiler macro should ensure that the common case of

```
(fmt t '("~&foo: ~S~%"
         "bar~%") ...)
```

will have no run-time cost at all.

Comment: Interesting, I favor the other answer, though, because of simplicity.